# How to save images and text to sqlite database downloaded as json from internet

Tags: android

I am working on an app that would fetch data from internet using json string and populate in recycler view but my app crashes without internet support. I need a way to store data(text and image) into SQLite database so that my app would work even in absence of any internet and show all information downloaded earlier and saved in SQLite and would sync when the online data is changed. Is there any tutorial that would explain this.

Answer (score 0):

There are loads on the internet. You can simply do a Google search for "SQLite Tutorial Android"

Here are a few:

[Tutorial Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

[Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

[Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Use realm mobile database it is very easy and fast.

Here are the links:

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/

https://realm.io/